# Parsing text file and store these values in python dictionary

Tags: python

I have text file as follows

```
ID   Value 1    Value 2

1     0.8        0.08
2     0.10       0.11
3     11         12
```

Now the issue is i have to store these values in python dictionary and write to a file..

Can anybody help me how to do this using python

Thanks
N

Comment: +1 to what Joe said, tell us how would you go about it, and we'll provide advice and corrections

Comment: If your data is already in a file, and you want to read this file into a dictionary and then back out to a file, the only thing this will seem to accomplish is removing lines with duplicate keys.  Is this what you want to accomplish?  What are the keys?  IDs?  If so, are the IDs already unique?

Answer (score 4):

Reading the file into a dict is fairly easy:

```
# use with statement to open the file
with open(file_name) as f:
    # skip first two lines (containing header) and split on whitespace
    # this creates a nested list like: [[val1, i1, i2], [val2, i1, i2]]
    lines = [x.split() for x in f.readlines()[2:]
    # use the list to create the dict, using first item as key, last as values
    d = dict((x[0], x[1:]) for x in lines)
```

This gives you a dict like:

```
{'1': ['0.8', '0.08'], '2': ['0.10', '0.11'], '3': ['11', '12']}
```

What format do you want to use to write the dict back out? If you want to write it back out into roughly the same format (I'm assuming it was originally space delimited csv):

```
import csv

writer = csv.writer(open(out_filename, 'w'), delimiter=' ')
# write header
writer.writerow(['ID', 'Value 1', 'Value 2'])
# write each row
for k,v in d.items():
    writer.writerow([k] + v)
```